# MySQL Timezone Resets after exiting server

Tags: mysql, timezone

I am running this code to set my database's timezone:

```
set time_zone = "US/Eastern"
```

This successfully changes the time to the correct time. However, as soon as I "exit" the database and re-enter, it reverts back to what I had originally changed it from. I have also tried this code:

```
set time_zone = "-04:00";
```

The same thing happens, it reverts to the servers default time. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> Abstract taken from another Stack Overflow Answer - [Adjusting for the
>   default time-zone setting on RDS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13424276/649408)

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
$ rds-describe-db-parameters default | grep "time_zone"
DBPARAMETER  default_time_zone                                                                   engine-default  string   static   false
```

To set the global value via SET GLOBAL you need to have the SUPER privilege which is not granted to you as a RDS user.

The only way to set the time_zone is on a per-connection basis

```
mysql> SET time_zone = timezone;
```

On my machines I've tried US/Eastern successfully but I got a quite old generation running.

To determine the timezones you have available log into your box

```
mysql -h yourboxhost.rds.amazonaws.com -u <youruser> -p
```

and type

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM mysql.time_zone_name;
```

You should get a list of installed and valid timezone names you can set on your instance

```
+----------------------------------------+--------------+
| Name                                   | Time_zone_id |
+----------------------------------------+--------------+
| Africa/Abidjan                         |            1 |
| Africa/Accra                           |            2 |
| Africa/Addis_Ababa                     |            3 |
| Africa/Algiers                         |            4 |
| Africa/Asmara                          |            5 |
| Africa/Asmera                          |            6 |
| Africa/Bamako                          |            7 |
| Africa/Bangui                          |            8 |
| Africa/Banjul                          |            9 |
| Africa/Bissau                          |           10 |
| Africa/Blantyre                        |           11 |
| Africa/Brazzaville                     |           12 |
| Africa/Bujumbura                       |           13 |
| Africa/Cairo                           |           14 |
etc...
```

You have to set the time_zone each time you connect to your database server

For example if you use the php Mysqli extension you can do this

```
$mysqli = mysqli_init();
mysqli_options($mysqli,MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND,"SET time_zone = 'Africa/Brazzaville'" );
mysqli_real_connect($mysqli,$host, $user, $pass,$dbName) or die ('Unable to connect');
```

Otherwise just manually ( in terms of let your database connector do it ) execute the `SET time_zone = '<YOUR_DESIRED_TIMEZONE>'` Query right after you've connected to your database

Answer (score 0):

IF you're not using RDS and you have access to your servers config then you can also set the default timezone in the server config. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone

I find it best to use the system time personally and make sure servers are set in the timezone I want.